# Django: Go to a URL with select option using GET and views.py or pure JavaScript gives a problem: Back to previous page requires 2 clicks

Tags: django, django-views

I show two solutions, one with GET, the other with Javascript. In both I need to double click the back button to come back to the previous page. I think this is a Django problem.

### GET case

In `templates` I have the following form:

```
  <form id="form-user" action="" method="GET">
    <select id="user" data-slug="{{x.user}}" onChange=selectChange(this)>
        <option value="">choose</option>
        <option value="view">View</option>
    </select>
    </form>
    <script>
    function selectChange(select) {
        var selectID = select.id;
        var value = select.value;
        
        if ($('#'+selectID).data('slug')) {
            var my_slug = $('#'+selectID).data('slug');
            var my_url = "{% url 'profiles:profile-detail' slug=none %}".replace(/none/, my_slug.toString());
        }
        
        if (value == 'view'){
            $("#form-"+selectID).attr("action", my_url);
            $("#form-"+selectID).submit();
        }  
    }
   </script>
```

In `views.py` I have:

```
 class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = Profile

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        myslug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        user = User.objects.get(username=myslug)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        return profile
```

In `urls.py` I have:

```
path('<slug>/', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile-detail'),
```

This approach takes me to the profile page of `{{x.user}}=user1`, however when I click the backward button in the browser, it goes from `mypath/user1` to `mypath/user1?`. I don't like this `?`. To go back to the previous page I would need to click the backward button twice. I would like to click it only once and remove this `?` transition step.

### Javascript case

`views.py` doesn't change as it is not needed. `template` is quite similar, we just remove the `method="GET"` in the HTML form tag, while  in the javascript we only change the following:

```
if (value == 'view'){
            window.location.href = my_url;
        }
```

Here also, I manage to go to the user page, however to come back to the previous page I need a double click, in this case it goes from `mypath/user1` to `mypath/user1` and then to the previous page.

I do believe it is a django problem but I'm not sure if we can solve it

## EDIT:

As suggested a request POST solution is not required in this case. Also `views.py` is better written as:

```
def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        return get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=slug)
```

However this doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What about just a link?

```
<a href="{% profiles:profile-detail slug=x.user %}">View</a>
```

Through CSS, you can style the link as a button or something else. This will trigger a GET request. A POST request makes not much sense, since you do not *change* the state: GET requests are supposed to have no side-effects, and POST requests are normally used to create, update, or remove data.

Your view can also be simplified: fetching the `User` is *not* necessary:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = Profile

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=myslug)
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to keep the form because it is within an iteration that has multiple options including create, update, and so on. if I choose GET, I dislike the `?` symbol in the backward step.

Comment: @statsconchris: then perhaps let the javascript just visit the URL instead of submitting the form?

Comment: For example I used `window.location.href = my_url;` instead of `submit();` in my JS function, but I still get the backward issue. I need to click twice the back button to come back to the previous page. In the JS case I don't have the `?` symbol in the transition step of course but still I need a double click. Thanks

Comment: @statsconchris: can you edit the question with the `urls`?

Comment: Ok I realized that I'm facing this issue only in Firefox. In Chrome it works fine... So it may be more difficult to solve now. I added the `urls`